# Singular perturbation of a first order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

In studying a reflection-transmission problem involving exotic materials, I have come across the following linear first-order differential equation:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
A\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(t) + Bg(t) = f(t),
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are constants, $g(t)$ is associated with the reflected wave, and $f(t)$ is a (finite) driving function associated with the incident wave.  Both $A$ and $B$ may be positive or negative.  I am interested in the behavior of the solution in the limit that $A\rightarrow0$.

I know there is an exact solution to Eq. \eqref{eq:1}, which is
\begin{equation}
g(t) = C e^{-Bt/A} + \frac{1}{A}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-B(t-t')/A}f(t')dt',
\end{equation}
where $C=0$ because $g(t)=0$ if $f(t)=0$.  However, I do not understand how this exact solution reduces to the case where $A=0$, which is $g(t)=B^{-1}f(t)$.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I've seen a lot of documents discussing asymptotic analyses of linear differential equations (for example, see [these lecture notes](http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~antoniosa/teach/mm13/notes.pdf)), but they all start with second-order equations.  Is this because there is inherently problematic with first-order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $A > 0$ and $B > 0$.   A change of variables $s = (t-t')/A$
in the integral gives you

$$ g(t) = C e^{-Bt/A} + \int_0^\infty e^{-Bs} f(t - A s) \; ds $$

Now as $A \to 0+$, $f(t-As) \to f(t)$ if $f$ is continuous.  Assuming $f$ is bounded, we can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem and this integral goes to

$$f(t) \int_0^\infty e^{-Bs}\; ds = B^{-1} f(t)$$

Comment: Thanks!  This helps a lot.  What if A<0, or B<0?  One of my concerns is that physically there is nothing dictating the signs of these quantities.

Comment: A change of variables $t \to -t$ in the differential equation changes $A$ to $-A$.  Or change $f$ to $-f$ and you switch the signs of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Wouldn't a change of variables $t\rightarrow-t$ also change the limits of integration from $(\infty,t)$ to $(-\infty,-t)$, which would make the integral diverge in the limit $A\rightarrow0$?

Comment: It changes the limits of integration from $(-\infty, t)$ to $(-t, +\infty)$, which makes the integral converge when $B/A < 0$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something.  When I assume $A<0$ and $B>0$, and make the substitution $\tau=-t$ in the differential equation, I get the integral $(-A)^{-1}\int_\tau^\infty e^{-B(\tau-\tau')/(-A)}f(-\tau')d\tau'$, which I don't think converges.  Making the substitution $s=(\tau-\tau')/(-A)$ leads to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-Bs}f(t + (-A)s)ds$, which doesn't converge.  What am I missing?

Comment: You're integrating over the wrong half-line.  If $A < 0$, let $\tilde{A}= -A$, $\tau = -t$, $g(t) = \tilde{g}(\tau)$, $f(t) = \tilde{f}(\tau)$, and the differential equation becomes $\tilde{A} \tilde{g}'(\tau) + B \tilde{g}(\tau) = \tilde{f}(\tau)$, which has the same form as your original, and is solved by
$$ \tilde{g}(\tau) = C e^{-B \tau/\tilde{A}} + \int_0^\infty e^{-Bs} \tilde{f}(\tau - \tilde{A}s)\; ds$$
i.e.
$$ g(t) = C e^{- B t/A} + \int_0^\infty e^{-Bs} f(t-As)\; ds$$